# SSRS only displays one row when parameter is used

Tags: reporting-services

We have an SSRS report that has been running perfectly at multiple sites for over a year.  It calls a MySQL stored procedure and displays the results in a table.  For one particular customer who just migrated to a new server, this report now only shows one row of the results.  It's a row that's early in the results but not necessarily the first row (not sure that has any significance).  Below are steps I have taken so far to troubleshoot.

- I've confirmed the procedure should return hundreds of rows by capturing the SQL via the slow query log, and running it directly on MySQL.  So I've ruled out the data, the procedure, and the connection to MySQL.
- This report does have grouping which I thought may be an issue, so I created a new report that calls the same procedure without any grouping and I get the same results.
- As far as we know all other customers are using SQL Server 2008 R2, or 2016.  This customer is using 2014.  We have confirmed this customer does have all the latest SQL Server updates.
- We have many other reports built in a similar way that work for this customer
- We tried replacing the report RDL with another copy thinking it was perhaps corrupt

There has been one thing I've found to get all rows to show up.  If I hard-code all parameters in the dataset, all rows will show up in the table.  If any parameters are passed in (it doesn't matter which ones, or how many), only one row of the results shows up.

**Dataset text examples**

Displays one row

```
Call sp_report(?,?)
```

Displays multiple rows

```
Call sp_report('A','B')
```

These examples both return the same number of rows from MySQL according to the slow query log, but SSRS displays a different number of rows.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.  I've been researching online and conducting many tests to try and figure this one out.

**Update 4/16/2019**
It's been 4 months and we still have not found a resolution for this.  Now some other customers are starting to report this same issues.  It still works for most customers and most reports, but there are a few cases where this occurs.

Comment: If you have not already done so, please try deleting the .data files and the .rptproj.rsuser files (in that order) for the directory. This can sometimes solve a multitude of problems! Also, if you are just using read-only stored procedures [which should be the case for most SSRS work] you should consider using functions for the SQL instead.

Comment: This is on a server.  Where would I find .data and .rptproj.rsuser files on a server?  I'm curious about your recommendation to use functions instead of stored procedures, I will give it a try, but could you elaborate on why that might help?

Comment: In generally, it would only be of help when running the "preview" [design mode of the rdl] from Visual Studio.  If it's already gone to the server, it wouldn't help ...

Comment: Of course using SQL functions is a different idea completely

Comment: Finally, the files are in the same directory as the .rdl file itself (at least on my system)

Comment: ok.  This works find on my machine when running in VS.  It actually runs fine on every other server it's deployed to as well.  It's only an issue on one particular server.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.

Do NOT use a Matrix Tablix in SSRS.

Use a Table.

I believe the problem is with how Matrix tablixes create or expect groups for the data rows.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).